# Internal Links Not Working Convert .HTM to .pdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to convert an `.htm` file from the SEC website to a `.pdf` and have the internal links work. I am successfully converting to `.pdf` using `wkhtmltopdf`, but all the internal links point me back to the first page.

```
wkhtmltopdf https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1594617/000119312514117433/d640354ds1a.htm test.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's an [issue](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3486) with `wkhtmltopdf` dealing with anchor tags that have no content. There's a [PR](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/pull/2957) that was opened in 2017 to resolve it, but it remains open.

As it turns out, your document does indeed have empty anchor tags, so that's probably the root cause:

```
<A NAME="toc640354_15"></A>
```

I would suggest using chrome to produce the pdf, with its `--headless` and `--print-to-pdf` flags. From your chrome installation directory, do:

```
chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="C:\path\to\file.pdf" https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1594617/000119312514117433/d640354ds1a.htm
```

Make sure you specify an absolute path to the output file or it doesn't seem to work, for whatever reason. The command will immediately return without any output or indication of success. Give it a few seconds to retrieve, render and write the file.

I tested with your document, and the links work perfectly.

Comment: Worked like a charm. On Mac went to `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS`. Could only figure out how to write pdf to current directory, but that's good for now!